# Remove first 3 characters from a field in the database

Tags: python, django

I've doctor entries in my database and I want to remove the first 3 characters from their name.

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)

    def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s %s" % (self.name, self.specialization)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('k.views.showDocProfile', args=[str(self.id)])
```

I've quite a few entires so removing then manually is not ideal.

Comment: self.name[3:] can get your job done, provided the self.name is a string type object.

Comment: Is it a one time operation, or you want to **always** remove first three letters? Is it transient operation (e.g. just a property that remove first three chars) or persistent (i.e. actually remove those from the DB, once and for all)?

Comment: I want a one time operation, remove those from the DB, once and for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One time all-db change:

```
for doctor in Doctor.objects.all():
   doctor.name = doctor.name[3:]
   doctor.save()
```

If you just need to mask the name for some use cases only, you can use a property field in your model

```
class Doctor(Model):
   name = CharField(...)

   @property
   def masked_name(self):
       return self.name[3:]

   # To access to property you just use doctor.masked_name on an instance of the Doctor class (it's a property, you don't have to call doctor.masked_name())
```